# Derivatives and expressions in R user defined function

Tags: r, function, expression, derivative

I'm brand new to coding and to R, I'm attempting to teach myself but I'm struggling a bit.

I'm trying to create a simple calculus function that will make the del operator ∇ =〈  / , / , / 〉act on a scalar. I can calculate the derivatives manually:

```
> c(D(expression(x*y*z),'x'),D(expression(x*y*z),'y'), 
D(expression(x*y*z),'z'))
[[1]]
y * z

[[2]]
x * z

[[3]]
x * y
```

Here is what I have so far, it obviously needs a bit more input. Can anybody help me out, it would be greatly appreciated :)

```
> grad <- function(scal) {
+    c(D(expression(scal),'x'),D(expression(scal),'y'),
     D(expression(scal),'z'))
+ }

> grad(x*y*z)
[1] 0 0 0
```

Comment: maybe `deriv` is better: `deriv(~x*y*z, c('x', 'y', 'z'))` calculates all the partial deivatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's try this:

```
grad <- function(scal){
    scal <- substitute(scal)
    sapply(c('x', 'y', 'z'), function(v) D(scal, v))
}

# > grad(x*y*z)
# $x
# y * z
# 
# $y
# x * z
# 
# $z
# x * y
```

note: if we replace `sapply` with `lapply`, the output will be exactly the one in your question. But I think with `names` the results is more informative.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass to `grad` an expression:

```
grad <- function(scal) {
   c(D(scal,'x'), D(scal,'y'), D(scal,'z'))
}
grad(expression(x*y*z))
```

The output given by `grad` is a `list` with 3 elements:

```
[[1]]
y * z

[[2]]
x * z

[[3]]
x * y
```